# while loop stopped at 1st loop because mysqli error

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

the error reads

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, double given in C:\xampp\htdocs\beta\jawa\isi.php on line 744

line 744 is : `while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($hasil))`

the full code :

```
<?php
$cari = "SELECT * FROM produk WHERE " ;
for ($i=0; $i<=$jml_kata; $i++) {
    $cari .= "deskripsi LIKE '%$pisah_kata[$i]%' OR nama_produk LIKE '%$pisah_kata[$i]%'";
    if ($i < $jml_kata ) {
        $cari .= " OR "; 
    }
}

$cari .= " ORDER BY id_produk DESC LIMIT 12";
$hasil  = mysqli_query($con,$cari);

while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($hasil)) {

    include "diskon_stok.php";
    echo"<div class='container_produk'>
        <a href='produk-$r[id_produk]-$r[produk_seo].html'><img src='http://images.rajafotocopy.com/foto_produk/$r[gambar]'/></a>
        <div class='detail'> 
            <span style='font-family : sui'>$r[nama_produk]</span><br />
            $divharga
        </div>
    </div>";
}
?>
```

I don't understand what's wrong with mysqli_result....? it is returning the 1st loop but after that it throws an error and expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result?

Comment: Something in your loop is overriding the value of $r

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Something in your loop is assigning to the variable `$hasil`. Show `[Code to execute]`

Comment: @JohnConde Not `$r`, `$hasil`.

Comment: `if ($r===false)` makes no sense. The test in `while()` means it will never get into the loop body when `$r === false`.

Comment: ok that was just my attempt to check for more errors

Comment: but wait, can something in `echo"";` overrides a query?

Comment: Is that the real code now? Then the problem is in `diskon_stok.php`, it's reusing the `$hasil` variable.

Comment: oh you're right! there is a variable called $hasil in diskon_stok.php... so that's what overriding the result. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in `diskon_stok.php` is doing:

```
$hasil = <something>;
```

where `<something>` is a number.

So when the loop repeats and it calls `mysqli_fetch_array($hasil)`, the variable no longer contains the query result, it contains this number, and that call fails.

Change the name of the variable you're using for the query result.

```
$result  = mysqli_query($con,$cari);

while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Comment: yes thank you. there is another variable $hasil in diskon_stok.php with value of double

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the while loop. While loops are for boolean (true/false) expressions, when you really want to loop through the list itself. Put more simply, a while loop is basically an if statement asked over and over again as long as it is true. For what you are asking for, I would recommend a foreach loop. You can set it up as something like this:

```
$resultArray = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil);

foreach($resultArray as $r){
      [Code to execute]
}
```

This should work more for your needs.

Comment: the while loop is okay, problem lies in a varible with same name as $hasil in a php file that was included, this variable value is overriding the mysqli_result